# HP TrueVision HD Camera - Cheese show black screen

Tags: camera

I have a HP laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 with a built in Truevision camera.

When running `cheese`the LED indicator next to camera lights up but the screen is black. The buttons in `cheese` is disabled. Pressing `q` to quit does not work so it seems like stucked. Clicking `x` in upper right corner works.

I have tried to run `sudo cheese` with the same negative result.

Testing with `xawtv` and `skype` also gives black sreen.

When testing with an external USB camera `cheese` works fine. Buttons is active and I can do recording. So the problem must be related to that specific camera not the application software.

I have done the following tests:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Aug 13 11:37 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Aug 13 11:37 /dev/video1

$ groups
joe adm cdrom sudo dip video plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare

$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru (usb-0000:03:00.3-3):
  /dev/video0
  /dev/video1
  /dev/media0

$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-ctrls
                     brightness 0x00980900 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=128 value=128
                       contrast 0x00980901 (int)    : min=0 max=255 step=1 default=32 value=32
                     saturation 0x00980902 (int)    : min=0 max=100 step=1 default=64 value=64
                            hue 0x00980903 (int)    : min=-180 max=180 step=1 default=0 value=0
 white_balance_temperature_auto 0x0098090c (bool)   : default=1 value=1
                          gamma 0x00980910 (int)    : min=90 max=150 step=1 default=120 value=120
                           gain 0x00980913 (int)    : min=4 max=8 step=1 default=4 value=4
           power_line_frequency 0x00980918 (menu)   : min=0 max=2 default=2 value=1 (50 Hz)
      white_balance_temperature 0x0098091a (int)    : min=2800 max=6500 step=1 default=4000 value=4000 flags=inactive
                      sharpness 0x0098091b (int)    : min=0 max=7 step=1 default=2 value=2
         backlight_compensation 0x0098091c (int)    : min=0 max=2 step=1 default=0 value=0
                 exposure_auto 0x009a0901 (menu)   : min=0 max=3 default=3 value=3 (Aperture Priority Mode)
              exposure_absolute 0x009a0902 (int)    : min=10 max=2500 step=1 default=156 value=156 flags=inactive
        exposure_auto_priority 0x009a0903 (bool)   : default=0 value=1


$ sudo dmesg | grep -i camera
[    1.669061] usb 1-3: Product: HP TrueVision HD Camera
[    2.843697] usb 1-3: Found UVC 1.00 device HP TrueVision HD Camera (04f2:b722)
[    2.892290] input: HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input9

$ uname -a
Linux HP-Laptop-15s-eq2xxx 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg -l | grep libuvc0 | column -t
ii  libuvc0  0.0.6-1.1  amd64  cross-platform  library  for  USB  video  devices
```

Edit1:

Testing with `ffplay` seems like `cheese`. It look up some data from the device but then freezes. The LED indicator turns but then it stuck. Here is the last lines:

```
chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
  nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

$ hwinfo --usb
06: USB 00.0: 0000 Unclassified device
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: 2UT6.Dt9VvvE5ii1
  Parent ID: k4bc.JEN+Lk01FR9
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:03:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0
  SysFS BusID: 1-3:1.0
  Hardware Class: unknown
  Model: "Chicony Electronics HP TrueVision HD Camera"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x04f2 "Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd"
  Device: usb 0xb722 "HP TrueVision HD Camera"
  Revision: "32.91"
  Driver: "uvcvideo"
  Driver Modules: "uvcvideo"
  Device File: /dev/input/event5
  Device Files: /dev/input/event5, /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:03:00.3-usb-0:3:1.0-event, /dev/input/by-id/usb-SunplusIT_Inc_HP_TrueVision_HD_Camera-event-if00
  Device Number: char 13:69
  Speed: 480 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v04F2pB722d3291dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00in00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: uvcvideo is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe uvcvideo"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #9 (Hub)
```

Any hint of what to check now is much welcome.

Comment: Does `ffplay /dev/video0` work? `ffplay /dev/video1`? (`ffplay` is part of the `ffmpeg` package)

Comment: I had the same problem. It was a privacy shutter. See  https://askubuntu.com/a/1368774/203091